# why doesn't my HttpContext.Request Property not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-express

[image]

I getting this error and I have no clue why I am pretty new to asp.net core so if you could take it easy on me that would be great.

```
 string port = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"];
```

> ERROR:
> Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  Elearn  C:\Users\source\elearn2Fin\Elearn\Elearn\Program.cs 29  Active

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access the request context outside the context of a request (you're trying to access it in `Program`).

Comment: By the way, your question title is a double negative (you're asking why it _is_ working).

Comment: @Llama haha I saw I fixed the title. i really need to use the Web.HttpContext.Current.Request in the program is there any other way i can get the URL/domain of my site inside the program file?